# Lion Full Screen menu bar doesn't slide down

Tags: cocoa, macos, fullscreen, menubar, osx-lion

I've got a small window that has no borders, titlebar, buttons, etc.  I want to support full -screen mode (the new Lion kind) and I basically have all that working -- I can switch into and out of fullscreen mode and the window resizes itself, etc, no problems.

However, when I move the mouse to the top of the screen, the Menu bar with the icon to close the full screen mode does not slide down.

How do I get that working?  Is it keyed off a style mask?  Something else?

Comment: Does the behavior change when you add a title bar?

Comment: Tried adding the title bar back to the original window (along with the close buttons, resizable mask, etc) and no effect :(

Comment: And I assume fullscreen works normally for you in other apps? Are you doing anything strange with event handling in this app?

Comment: A-ha, the key is in what you return for `- (NSApplicationPresentationOptions)window: (NSWindow *)window willUseFullScreenPresentationOptions: (NSApplicationPresentationOptions)proposedOptions` Need to add `NSApplicationPresentationAutoHideMenuBar | NSApplicationPresentationHideDock` to the returned values.  Gaa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A-ha, the key is in what you return for

```
 - (NSApplicationPresentationOptions)window: (NSWindow *)window willUseFullScreenPresentationOptions: (NSApplicationPresentationOptions)proposedOptions
```

You need to add `NSApplicationPresentationAutoHideMenuBar | NSApplicationPresentationHideDock` to the returned values in addition to `NSApplicationPresentationFullScreen`.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to do to make full screen mode work in Lion is to call `‑setCollectionBehavior:` on your window and pass in `NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenPrimary`.

You don't need to do anything else. All the kiosk-mode stuff is not necessary unless you are targeting 10.6 or earlier.

Comment: Turns out that you also need to set the presentation options for the window delegate as well …

Comment: Nope. Try it. Create an app with the standard template and just call `[window setCollectionBehavior: NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenPrimary]` in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`. No need to do anything else and the menu bar and dock are available.

Comment: Hrm. There's something weird going on, because I was doing exactly that and it was not showing up. I'm using a transparent window with no title bar or buttons or anything and non-standard shapes. Until I added those two constant values to the delegate method, I couldn't for the life of me get the system menu bar to come down …